# React Testing Library jest.fn() toHaveBeenCalled() not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

Component:

```
const MyComp = ({ handler }) => {
  return <button onClick={handler}>Test</button>
};
```

Test:

```
it('Calls the handler', async () => {
   const handler = jest.fn();
   render(<MyComp handler={handler} />);

   const button = screen.getByRole('button', { name: /Test/i });
   await fireEvent(button, new MouseEvent('click'));

   expect(handler).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

Expected number of calls: >= 1
Received number of calls: 0

Comment: Why not userEvent.click? I don't think fireEvent returns a promise.

Comment: (Specifically to get _this_ to work, looks like your event needs to bubble, as in the example in the docs: https://testing-library.com/docs/dom-testing-library/api-events. Or just use the convenience method.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Three options:

- Make the event bubble, as shown in [the example](https://testing-library.com/docs/dom-testing-library/api-events/#fireevent) (it doesn't return a promise, no `await` needed):

  ```
  fireEvent(button, new MouseEvent("click", { bubbles: true }));
  ```
- Use the [convenience method](https://testing-library.com/docs/dom-testing-library/api-events/#fireeventeventname), which adds [default event properties](https://github.com/testing-library/dom-testing-library/blob/54bfa48a5417a4cb588b24dec2685eaa3436fa69/src/event-map.js#L80-L83) including bubbling (likewise):

  ```
  fireEvent.click(button);
  ```
- Use [`userEvent`](https://testing-library.com/docs/user-event/intro) (*does* return a promise, as of v14):

  ```
  await userEvent.click(button);
  ```

Answer (score 1):

Try using `userEvent.click`, like this

```
it('Calls the handler', async () => {
   const handler = jest.fn();
   render(<MyComp handler={handler} />);

   const button = screen.getByRole('button', { name: /Test/i });
   await userEvent.click(button);

   expect(handler).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```